# Bash globbing that matches all files except those with a specific extension, that works on filenames that include dot characters

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards

I'm doing some stuff with audio files, most but not all of which are mp3 files. Now I want to run some commands on only the files which are not mp3 files, or only those which don't have a `.mp3` extension.

I consider myself pretty good at regular expressions, but not so much at file globbing, which is subtly different in unexpected ways.

I looked around and learned from other SO & SE answers that Bash has "extended globbing" that allows me to do this:

```
file ../foo/bar/*.!(mp3)
```

But some of my filenames have dots in them besides the one forming the filename extension:

```
../foo/bar/Naked_Scientists_Show_19.10.15.mp3
../foo/bar/YWCS_ep504-111519-pt1_5ej4_41cc9320.mp3_42827d48daefaa81ec09202e67fa8461_24419113.mp3
../foo/bar/eLife_Podcast_19.09.26.mp3
../foo/bar/gdn.sci.080428.bg.science_weekly.mp3
```

It seems the glob matches from the first dot onward, rather than from the last dot. I looked at the documentation but it seems they are far less powerful than regexes. But I didn't really grok everything as I don't spend that much time on *nix shells.

Have I missed some way that I can still do this with Bash globbing? If not, a way to achieve the same thing with find or some other tool would still be worth knowing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`*.!(mp3)` matches on `foo.bar.mp3` because that's `foo.` followed by `bar.mp3` which is *not `mp3`*.

You want `!(*.mp3)` here, which matches anything that doesn't end in `.mp3`.

If you want to match files whose name contains at least one `.` (other than a leading one which would make them a hidden file) but don't end in `.mp3`, you could do `!(*.mp3|!(*.*))`.

In any case, note that unless your `bash` was built with `--enable-extended-glob-default`, you'll need to `shopt -s extglob` for that ksh glob operator to be available.

Answer (score 6):

There's also [the `GLOBIGNORE` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion):

> The `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable may be used to restrict the set of
>   file names matching a pattern. If `GLOBIGNORE` is set, each matching
>   file name that also matches one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is
>   removed from the list of matches. If the `nocaseglob` option is set,
>   the matching against the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is performed without
>   regard to case. The filenames `.` and `..` are always ignored when
>   `GLOBIGNORE` is set and not null. However, setting `GLOBIGNORE` to a
>   non-null value has the effect of enabling the `dotglob` shell option,
>   so all other filenames beginning with a ‘`.`’ will match. To get the
>   old behavior of ignoring filenames beginning with a ‘`.`’, make ‘`.*`’
>   one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE`. The `dotglob` option is disabled
>   when `GLOBIGNORE` is unset.

```
$ touch a.b.mp3 .c.mp3 foo.tgz .bar
$ echo *
a.b.mp3 foo.tgz
$ shopt -s extglob; echo *.!(mp3)
a.b.mp3 foo.tgz
$ GLOBIGNORE='*.mp3'; echo *
.bar foo.tgz
```

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way I can think of:

```
find ${path-to-folder} -type f  | grep -vE ".*\.mp3$"
```

You find all files in a folder and pipe it to a reverse extended grep:

Find all files in a location

```
find ${path-to-folder} -type f
```

Reverse grep and use a regex to filter by extension

```
grep -vE ".*\.mp3$"
```

Grep flags:

- `-v` reverse grep
- `-E` extended grep (use of regex)

Regex explained:

- `.*` means from 0 to whatever char count, any possible char
- `\.` looks for the actual dot
- `mp3` for the string that forms the extension
- `$` stands for EOL

Comment: Or just `grep -v '\.mp3$'` (no need for `-E` as there's no extended operator there), no need for `.*` if you're not using the `-x` option. That assumes the file paths don't contain newline characters though.

Comment: True, there's always room to improve :-)

Comment: As long as you’re bringing `find` into it, why not ``find "${folder}" -type f ! -name '*.mp3'``?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', rather `LC_ALL=C find "${folder}" -type f ! -name '*.mp3'` as with some find implementations (including GNU find on GNU systems), you may still see filenames ending in `.mp3` if the rest of the file name is encoded in a charset different from that of the user's locale (not uncommon for mp3's).

Comment: @Stéphane: so you’re saying that `find "${folder}" -name '*.mp3'` might *not* find “E=mc².mp3”, “.mp3”, “→.mp3” (cat likes pizza), “〇一二三四五六七八九十.mp3” (Kanij), “۰۱۲۳۴ ۵۶۷۸۹.mp3” (Arabic), “не бійся жити.mp3” (Ukrainian for “Don't be afraid to live”) or even “Stéphane.mp3”, if the locale is `en_US`?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', it may fail to find files whose names are encoded in a charset other than that of the user's locale. I don't know what charset your `en_US` locale uses, but if it's UTF-8 for instance (see output of `locale charmap`), and that ² is encoded in ISO8859-1 for instance (`touch $'E=mc\xb2.mp3'`) then on a GNU system, GNU `find` will no find it.  if your `en_US` uses iso8859-1, then you should be fine regardless of what charset the files are encoded in, as all bytes there are assumed to make up a character.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not ideal for your situation but I was wondering how about making a function in pure `Bash` and then passing the extension as an arg, which can be handy if you want to add it in your `bashrc` and you want to do the same thing in the future, like the following

So, basically what we are doing is the regex check for your desired extension.

```
for file in *; do
  if [[ $file =~ \.mp3$ ]]; then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

Implementing it in a function: This would output all the files with specific extension in your current directory.

```
getFileByExt(){
local extension="$1"
if (( $# == 1 )); then
for file in *; do
  if [[ $file =~ \.$extension$ ]]; then
    echo $file
  fi
done
else
  echo "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} <extension>" 
## If run from bashrc, return the name of function
fi
}
```

Now, for example to get all the files with `mp3` extension, it would be as simple as doing:

```
getFileByExt mp3
```

And to get files without specefic extension: This would output all the files that do not have specific extension in your current directory.

```
getFileWithoutExt(){
local extension="$1"
if (( $# == 1 )); then
for file in *; do
  if [[ ! $file =~ \.$extension$ ]]; then
    echo $file
  fi
done
else
  echo "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} <extension>"
fi
}
```

Similarly to get files without `mp3` extension just simply do:

```
getFileWithoutExt mp3
```

For more info:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407184/how-to-check-the-extension-of-a-filename-in-a-bash-script

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278990/easiest-way-to-check-for-file-extension-in-bash/18280350