# Exclude a filename suffix from glob match

Tags: bash, wildcards

I've read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) but couldn't find the answer to what I wanted to achieve. I have the following files:

```
$ ls 
a  a.  a.b  ab  a.c  ac
```

I have the `extglob` shell option enabled. I want to exclude all files ending in `".c"`. This means that I want to see these 5 files: `a a. a.b ab ac`.

```
$ echo *!(.c)
a a. a.b ab a.c ac
```

Well, that hasn't worked. It still shows me `a.c`. I don't understand why.

Some examples I've seen would suggest that I need the `.` before the `!`:

```
$ echo *.!(c)
a. a.b
```

But that is not the same as what I'm asking. It has ignored some wanted files: a, ab, ac.

Is there a glob pattern I can use to exclude *only* files ending in `.c`?

Comment: Similar (and I'm pretty sure there's an exact duplicate): [Bash globbing that matches all files except those with a specific extension, that works on filenames that include dot characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556545)

Comment: exact enough. `a.c` is `a.c` followed by the empty string which is not `.c`. Or `a.` followed by `c` which is not `.c`.